# SQL Bulk Query Inserts

Tags: sql, vb.net

So I have a list of id's stored in a JsonArray. Currently, I am looping through the id's like so:

```vb
'Insert ids into table
For Each userId As Int32 In idList
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_ids (id) VALUES (" & userId & ");"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

When that runs, it executes about 100 queries give or take, depending on the size of the id list. What I am trying to do, is use a bulk query so that rather than doing 100 queries to the database, I can do them all in one query. I have been looking at using DataSets and BulkCopy but I am not sure how I would implement it.

Is there a better solution?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not thrilled with using string concatenation like that to build the query. The technique is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks, even if this particular case is _likely_ (not guaranteed) to be safe.

Comment: I am escaping before I insert the id into the id list. So thats not the issue. I am just trying to convert 100 inserts into one single batch query.

Comment: Escaping and sanitizing is not an okay way protect again injection. You need to _quarantine_ data through use of parameterized queries.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So use something like "Parameters.Add("@id", userId);"

Comment: Exactly. This has other benefits I'm writing about in answer that's almost ready.

Comment: I think it would be a bit faster if you use parameters, since it won't be concidered a new query on each Execute. You could also make a store proc and pass an array as the parameter. Depending on the DB, you could use SqlBulkCopy  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Setting up to do a [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) or [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) would likely be more efficient, but with just about 100 rows it's questionable whether you'd see a noticeable improvement, or even any improvement at all... the time spent massaging the data to a BULK INSERT-friendly format could easily outweigh the database throughput gain here. You also need to weigh whether the increased code complexity and introduction of a new technique would justify any improvement that you did see.

Instead, I'd just go for keeping the the same query and connection objects in your loop, like this:

```vb
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_ids (id) VALUES ( @UserID )" )

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Integer)
    cn.Open()

    'Insert ids into table
    For Each userId As Int32 In idList
        cmd.Parameters("@UserID").Value = userId
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
```

In addition to the nice side benefit of keeping your code safe from sql injection attacks, this code should be faster than what you have, because the database will be able to cache that execution plan during your loop, and thus skip the compile and generate plan steps as it executes individual query.

If this insert happens at regular intervals (such as once per day), you might also take a look at this KB article about using minimal logging:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I know that because its only about 100 or so queries, it wont make a huge difference, but its more of me wanting to learn how to do it all at once.

Comment: When doing "command.Parameters("@UserID") = userId" I am getting the error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter'"